# How to get Photoshop's file history data programmatically

Tags: javascript, photoshop, history, adobe-illustrator

I tried to make a program to aggregate the file history of Photoshop and Illustrator, so that I will query and open the files conveniently.
I think there should be a file to store this information, like the vscode's `storage.json`.
But I didn't find the data file and I didn't know where to read this information.

I work on both Windows 10 and macOS.

Comment: You can access Photoshop's history state with `app.activeDocument.historyStates[x]` but it's not very verbose, but it might be what you're after.

Comment: @GhoulFool I believe OP is after File > Recent Opened Files list

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy it was a 50/50 gamble. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the entries in Windows Registry will help you if the embedded javascript has no working option. Go to the key

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\MediaBrowser\MRU\Photoshop\FileList

You will see many keys whose names are time values. Inside each of them, the default value is the file name relative to the moment it was last opened.

Comment: I found the key in Registry, but there is nothing.
I have tried to install a new Photoshop and edit some pictures. I can see the history list on Phototshop's welcome page, but nothing in the Windows Registry.
I miss some config in Photoshop?

Comment: What Photoshop version are you using?

Comment: 22.5.0, and i had tried cc 2020 and 2018.
Because of vmware, i can install different version to test, but the results are in the same